# If $A$ is a Krull ring of $K$, then $A \cap K'$ is also a Krull ring for $K' \subset K$.

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> If $A$ is a Krull ring of $K$, then $A \cap K'$ is also a Krull ring for $K' \subset K$ (where $K'$ is a subfield of $K$).

What's confusing me is that $K'$ may not contain the uniformising element $t$ of $R_{\lambda}$ where $R_{\lambda}$ is in the defining family of $A$. How do we know that the valuation is still discrete?

Comment: First of all, not every Krull ring is a DVR.  Secondly, you can have a DVR $A\subset K$ with uniformizing parameter $t$ and $K'\subset K$ subfield with $t\notin K'$ and $A\cap K'$ is still a DVR.  Consider $A = \mathbb{Q}[x]_{(x)}$ with uniformizing parameter $x$, $K = \mathbb{Q}(x)$, $K' = \mathbb{Q}(x^2)$.  Then $A\cap K' = \mathbb{Q}[x^2]_{(x^2)}$ which is a DVR.

Comment: @Callus Thanks. I'm sorry, I meant "$K'$ may not contain the uniformising element $t$ of $R_{\lambda}$" where $R_{\lambda}$ is in the defining family of $A$. I just wrote $A$ by mistake...Anyways, thanks for the counterexample, but I'm still not sure how to proceed with the proof.

Comment: @Callus Initially, I was planning to take the minimum power of the uniformising element which *does* exist in $K'$ (say $t^n$) and then define $t \mapsto n \mapsto 1$ by taking the composition of the discrete valuation $\nu: K \rightarrow \Bbb{Z}$ and $n\Bbb{Z} \rightarrow \Bbb{Z}$ with $n \mapsto 1$. But this will not work because we may have $t^m \in K'$ with gcd(m,n)=1.

Comment: I'm kind of thinking out loud here which is not great for a comment, but if $t^n$ and $t^m$ are in $K'$, then $t^{am+bn}\in K'$ for any $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$, so if $gcd(m,n)=1$, then $t\in K'$, by Bezout's Lemma

Comment: @Callus, Thanks for the comment. So if $t^m$ is in $K'$ with $gcd(m,n)=w$ where $w < n$, then by Bezout's Lemma we have $t^w \in K'$. But this is a contradiction since we assumed that $t^n$ was the smallest power of $t$ contained in $K'$, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the restriction to $K'$ of all discrete valuations defining the Krull domain $A$. These are discrete or improper. Now get rid the improper ones and you are done.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure if I understood the answer. As far as I understand...when you say "consider the restriction to $K'$ of all discrete valuations defining the Krull domain $A$", you mean we should look at what happens when we send $t^m$ (where $t$ is the uniformising element) to $1$ for any $m \in \Bbb{N}$. And by "get rid the improper ones", you mean we should basically take the minimum $m$. Is that correct? I just want to know if I understood it correctly.

Comment: I didn't think this way: when I said that I've meant two things, depend on what you are working with. If you work with DVRs, then I mean to consider $R_{\lambda}\cap K'$, while if you work with discrete valuations then I mean to restrict $v_{\lambda}:K\to\mathbb Z\cup\{\infty\}$ to $K'$, that is, to consider its restriction (as a function) to $K'$. Now one can have $R_{\lambda}\cap K'=K'$ (and this means improper), and such $R_{\lambda}$ can be read off. (In terms of valuations, if $v_{\lambda}(x)\ge0$ for all $x\in K'$ then this valuation is improper, and get rid of it.)

Comment: Let me mention that my answer shows that $A∩K′$ is a Krull domain, but not necessarily for $K′$, that is, its field of fractions can be smaller than $K′$. (For such an example see [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1609113/121097).)